# Change date format in datatable using Laravel and Symfony

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I'm trying to change the format of a date field in the DataTable, so not in the form! These fields are created using the formbuilder Symfony. I have no clue how to do this, or were to place it. I Have tried to change the format of the date in DateForm.php but that doesn't change the data in the datatable. I hope this is enough code to understand the situation, else just tell me.

My datatable DateTable.php

```
class DateTable extends BaseDataTable{
    use FilterableDataTableTrait;
    public function ajax()
    {
        $view = view('admin::crud.actions');

        $query = $this->query();

        return $this->datatables
            ->eloquent($query)
            ->addColumn('id', function ($item) {
                return $item->id;
            })->addColumn('action', function ($item) use ($view) {
                $view = $item->relation ? view('admin::date.actions') : view('admin::date.actions');
                $view->with('item', $item);
                return $view->render();
            })->make(true);
    }

    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->columns($this->getColumns())

            ->addAction(['title' => '', 'width' => '100px'])
            ->ajax('')
            ->parameters(array_merge($this->getBuilderParameters(), ['autoWidth' => false]));
    }
 }
```

My form DateForm.php:

```
class DateForm extends AbstractType{
private $data;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $this->data = $builder->getData();
    return $builder
        ->add('date', 'date',
            [
                'required' => true,
            ])
        ->add('description', 'textarea', ['required' => true
        ]);
}
}
```

Comment: look into Carbon http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ for date time management. Once saved in the database you have to create a script to change it everywhere and the date format has to be changed as well in the database according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Laravel Carbon for it:

```
$date->format('d.m.Y'); //or another time format
```

before inserting data into the DB.